# Is the word "etc." appropriate for use in a newspaper article with an informal tone?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Or should I replace it with other words? (such as, for example...)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, etc is fine. A quick google search of the British newspapers the Daily Mail and Guardian gives numerous examples. The Guardian style guide says it should be "etc", not "e.t.c." - https://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-e.